# Delay execution of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, delay

I'm calling some JavaScript from within my PHP code, but I want the second part to hold on for 5 seconds.

I found something like `setTimeOut(something, time)` (JS) and `.delay(time)` (JQuery), but none of them seems applicable in my situation.

Here is my PHP:

```
$feedback = '<script>
               $(document).ready(function() {
                 noty({"text": "Yep, you did it",
                   "closeButton": true, "closeOnSelfClick": true,
                   "closeOnSelfOver": false, "modal": false
                 });
               });
             </script>

             <script>
                window.location = "http://www.mysite.be/new/index.php";        
             </script>';
```

It's the second part (the `window.location`) I want to pause for like 5 seconds.
But I can't figure out how to do so. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace the second part by:

```
<script>
  window.setTimeout( function() {
    window.location = "http://www.mysite.be/new/index.php";
    }, 5 * 1000 );
</script>
```

This executes the anonymous function after 5s (see [MDN documentation `setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)).

Comment: Why is your answer better (or worse) then the one from Juicy? :-)

Comment: @Michiel Just read in the comments to his questions and decide for yourself. I personally do not put strings as parameters to `eval()`-like functions. But as is pointed out in the comments, it shouldn't make much difference here.

Comment: @Michiel, it's nicer because of mine uses technique that may very easily lead to mess in code and harden understanding of what code does. Practically it's leads to the same result.

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout` fits your needs:

```
setTimeout('window.location = "http://www.mysite.be/new/index.php";', 5000);
```

As not everyone is ok with `eval`, this may also be done with function call if `eval` isn't for you:

```
var redirect = function(){
  window.location = "http://www.mysite.be/new/index.php"
}
setTimeout(redirect, 5000)
```

BTW, While [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) of jQuery may be used to achieve what you want it's not suited for that:

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

Comment: [eval is evil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don%27t_use_eval!)

Comment: Even in that case, the (unnecessary) performance drawback remains.

Comment: @Sirko, I'm not arguing about usage of eval in generic, but [you will not gain any performance by replacing eval with function call in that case](http://jsperf.com/settimeout-eval-vs-reference)

Comment: Thanks @JuicyScripter for your answer (and the complementary documentation)!